# Зачем в MinGWw64 есть Clang и его пакеты?

Tags: c++, компиляция, clang, llvm, mingw-w64

Всем привет! Я решил обновить GCC который по дефолту шел с Code::Blocks чтобы пощупать С++20 и столкнулся с проблемой, что MinGWw64 на сайте имеет 2 варианта, один классический с GCC+MinGW плюшками, а второй с внезапно CLang и его непонятными прибамбасами. Зачем они нужны и при чем тут вообще Clang если Clang это другой компилятор и он тут ни при чем?(скрин ниже прилагается)

P.S. доп. вопрос, может кто знает, я скачал с llvm сайта Clang установщик .exe и поставил его в папку. В IDE указал путь до это папки, вроде как Clang распознался и нашелся, но при попытке компиляции пишет, что не может найти, стандартные библиотеки, т.е. iostream/stdio.h банально не видит, как так? Я читал в одном из вопросов, что можно какими-то костылями через линуксоидство и mysys2 что-то делать, но есть ли вариант для простых смертных без левых прослоек и программ?
[image: Что выбрать?]

Comment: Очевидно затем, чтобы использовать clang. clang требует наличия стандартной библиотеки, а не распространяет ее с собой, подобно vc++ или g++.

Comment: @user7860670 так а зачем в mingw запихнули Clang? Если я качаю mingw то мне не нужен clang,а если инужен,то лучше скачать отдельно? И как вообще выбирать чем компилить,когда в архиве там никакого четкого разделения на clang и gcc не вижу

Comment: Если его качать отдельно, то в нагрузку понадобится mingw или vc++. *"никакого четкого разделения "* - ¿неужели там нет clang?

Comment: @user7860670 ну он там есть, но намешан в папках,а так выглядит как обычный Mingw. И как его использовать тогда,если он непонятно как встроен?

Comment: ¿Я не понимаю, что мешает его использовать, вызвав clang.exe?

Comment: @user7860670 ну то, что я использую ide codeblocks и у него нет опции "мешанина из компиляторов", либо 1, либо другой. И то, что лежит в архиве проименовано и сделано будто там только MinGW,о чем ide и думает. А clang закинуть в дебри архива.

Comment: *"какими-то костылями через линуксоидство и mysys2 что-то делать"* Это вы зря. MSYS2 - это самая нормальная поставка компиляторов для винды (VS не считаю). С кучей готовых библиотек в пакетах, и прочим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге выяснилось, что Clang там есть просто потому что можно. Выгода его использования в одной папке с MinGWw64 в том, что библиотеки для Clang-а берутся сразу из MinGW без указания пути вручную (у Clang своих стандартных библиотек нет). Т.е. это действительно набор компиляторов 2в1 и выбирать можно какой хочешь, главное настроить верно пути.